# Numpy savetxt saves 1D array as column

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy

I use loadtxt to initialize array.

```
source = np.loadtxt('source.txt').astype(int)
```

After that I use this array in function, which body is:

```
file = open('johnson.txt', 'ab')
first = increase(np.argsort(source[0]))
np.savetxt(file, first, delimiter='-', fmt='%i')
file.close()
```

As a result, in txt file I should have this:

```
7-1-3-6-2-4-8-5
```

But I have this:

```
7
1
3
6
2
4
8
5
```

I have to open file in binary mode, because I need to append another rows to file. So, how can I fix that?
Thank you!

Comment: Try `np.savetxt(file, np.atleast_2d(first), delimiter='-', fmt='%i')` or `np.savetxt(file, first.reshape(-1, 1), delimiter='-', fmt='%i')`

Comment: `np.atleast_2d(first)` is working perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`savetxt` iterates on the input array, and writes each 'row' to a new line.  For the typical 2d array that would be a row.  But for a 1d array that would be an element.

So change your write to saving a 2d array:

```
np.savetxt('test.txt', [first], delimiter=..., fmt=...)
```

Assuming `first` is a 1d array, then `np.array([first])` is 1 row 2d,  `first[None,:]` would also work (or a `reshape`).

To append lines, open the file in 'a' append mode.  'wb'` binary doesn't help.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! It became much clearer for me.